# How to composite multiple PNG into a single PNG using GTK/Cairo

Tags: c, animation, graphics, gtk, cairo

I'm somewhat new to GTK and very new to Cairo. I've been tasked to create an application that needs to take a PNG as a background and composite multiple PNG files that contains letters and numbers onto the background PNG so that I end up with a single PNG that can then be transformed, rotated, scaled etc. Any hints, tutorials, code samples that I might find useful? As is the case with GTK, the Cairo documentation appears somewhat lacking for a beginner trying to do something more complex than drawing shapes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at this simple example. It uses only cairo:

```
#include <cairo.h>

int main()
{
    //Load a few images from files
    cairo_surface_t *surf1 = cairo_image_surface_create_from_png("a.png");
    cairo_surface_t *surf2 = cairo_image_surface_create_from_png("b.png");

    //Create the background image
    cairo_surface_t *img = cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, 100, 100);

    //Create the cairo context
    cairo_t *cr = cairo_create(img);

    //Initialize the image to black transparent
    cairo_set_source_rgba(cr, 0,0,0, 1);
    cairo_paint(cr);

    //Paint one image
    cairo_set_source_surface(cr, surf1, 0, 0);
    cairo_paint(cr);

    //Paint the other image
    cairo_set_source_surface(cr, surf2, 50, 50);
    cairo_paint(cr);

    //Destroy the cairo context and/or flush the destination image
    cairo_surface_flush(img);
    cairo_destroy(cr);

    //And write the results into a new file
    cairo_surface_write_to_png(img, "result.png");

    //Be tidy and collect your trash
    cairo_surface_destroy(img);
    cairo_surface_destroy(surf1);
    cairo_surface_destroy(surf2);

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Thank you Rodrigo, this is a very good example!

For all **C# programmers**, here is the exact same example translated into C#. I made only one small change in SetSourceRGBA() - to allow for a transparent background image instead of black:

```
Using Cairo;

    //Load a few images from files
    ImageSurface surf1 = new ImageSurface("a.png");
    ImageSurface surf2 = new ImageSurface("b.png");

    //Create the background image
    ImageSurface img = new ImageSurface(Format.Argb32, 200, 200);

    //Create the cairo context
    Context cr = new Context(img);

    //Initialize the image to black transparent
    // cr.SetSourceRGBA(255,255,255,1); // This will create the background image with white background
    // cr.SetSourceRGBA(0,0,0,1);       // This will create the background image with black background
    cr.SetSourceRGBA(0,0,0,0);          // This creates the background image with transparent background
    cr.Paint ();


    //Paint one image
    cr.SetSourceSurface(surf1,0,0);
    cr.Paint();

    //Paint the other image
    cr.SetSourceSurface(surf2, 25, 50);
    cr.Paint();

    //Destroy the cairo context and/or flush the destination image
    img.Flush();

    //And write the results into a new file
    img.WriteToPng("result.png");

    //Be tidy and collect your trash
    img.Dispose();
    img.Destroy();
    surf1.Destroy ();
    surf2.Destroy();
```